# Bash initialize variable to a string that contains quotes and backslahes

Tags: bash

I have a string containing quotes and backslahes:

`-options \'{"version": "http"}\'`

I would like to initialize a variable `PARAM` with this string.
How this can be done in bash?

I thought of adding it to an array: `PARAMS=(-options \'{"version": "http"}\')`

but the output I am getting is: `-options '{version: http}'` i.e. without the slashes.

Expected output: `-options \'{"version": "http"}\'`

Can someone please suggest?

Comment: What are you going to use it for exactly? Is it supposed to be one string or two separate arguments for a command? Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). At first glance it seems like this isn't a duplicate of [the question Barmar closed under](/q/13365553/), but I can't tell what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to append `-options \'{"version": "http"}\'` to an existing line in a file. Yes, it is a single string containing a parameter `-version` and its value `\'{"version": "http"}\'`.

Comment: You don't need to include the single quotes as literal characters, unless you plan on passing the string to `eval` eventually (which is probably a bad idea in the first place).`PARAMS=(-options '{"version": "http"}')` should suffice. Later, you'll run some command like `foo "${PARAMS[@]"`; the JSON object will be preserved as a single object without the need to provide syntactic quotes around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks ok to me.

```
test="-client-options \\'{\"quic-version\": \"h3\"}\\'"
echo "$test"
t2=("$test" "etc")
echo ${t2[@]}
```

Escape every inner " and double escape for a persisting escape